# What does window['someKeyword'] mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What does `window['someKeyword']` mean in JavaScript?

I guess the window is the [DOM window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window), but the syntax to retrieve a property is `window.propertyName` in the reference I found, not `window['propertyName']`. Are these two ways to retrieve the property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access a field of an `object` in Javascript there are two ways.

let's this is an object

```
obj = {name:'Object1'};
```

You can access `name` field by two ways

```
obj.name // returns 'Object1'
obj['name'] //returns 'Object1'
```

besically `[]` this method is useful when you have to access a field using a variable like bellow

```
var obj = {name:'Object1'}
var field = 'name'

obj[field] //returns 'Object1' because it will put value of field in `[]`
```